# Why doesn't my while statement end?

Tags: c++

I've created this program to calculate scores of peoples tests and count the number of grades. What i want to happen is that when the user enters "//" when the program asks "Enter student Name", the while statement should end, or that's what i assume should happen. What actually happens is that i type "//" then the program asks for the score, then the while statement ends. Why is this and what should i do to fix it?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name, grade;
    int score;
    int count1 = 0;
    int acount = 0;
    int bcount = 0;
    int ccount = 0;
    int dcount = 0;
    int fcount = 0;
    while (name != "//") {
        cout << "Enter Student Name \n";
        cin >> name;
        cout << "Enter Student Score \n";
        cin >> score;
        count1 += 1;
        if (score >= 90) {
            grade = "A";
            acount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
        else if (score >= 80) {
            grade = "B";
            bcount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
        else if (score >= 70) {
            grade = "C";
            ccount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
        else if (score >= 60) {
            grade = "D";
            dcount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
        else if (score <= 59) {
            grade = "F";
            fcount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
    };
    cout << "Summary Report \n" << "Total Students Count: " << count1 << endl;
    cout << "A student count: " << acount << endl;
    cout << "B student count: " << bcount << endl;
    cout << "C student count: " << ccount << endl;
    cout << "D student count: " << dcount << endl;
    cout << "F student count: " << fcount << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The best tool to use for this is your debugger.

Comment: Well, shouldn't you *first* collect `name`, and *then* compare it to `//`? You are doing these two the wrong way round.

Comment: I'm really confused, the program as written does exactly what you describe: It reads the stundent name, reads the score, checks the score, and then checks the loop condition. What's there to explain?

Comment: Because if you run the program, and then type "//" it then asks for the score and displays "// 45 F" assuming i entered 45, but i want it to end the while statement before it asks the score

Comment: "i type "//" then the program asks for the score" . But that's exactly what you wrote in your code! Right after asking for name you are asking for score. Why did you expect it to behave differently?

Comment: you guys act as if i know c++ i dont which is why im asking the questions. what i want is when name="//" the program will go to the outside of the while statement, but when i type // it doesnt end til it asks for the score

Comment: @alexanderbowen it's not about "knowing" C++. Lines of code are executed from top to bottom one after the other. You couldn't have written that code without knowing that. The sequence of events in the code is really self-evident, regardless of proficiency with the language.

Comment: @alexanderbowen:  as others have said, the flow/handling in your program is behaving AS WRITTEN, or it is doing exactly what you said to do! After the name is input, it is AFTER the point checked at the while loop, as the code will not "automatically stop" in the middle of the loop and score WILL be the next statement.  What you could do instead, is make the loop `while (true)`, and then after the name input (and before the 'score' output)  check the name value `if(name == "//") { break; }` to exit the loop after the name entry. Know that there are many other ways to handle the task too.

Comment: Youre not understanding my point, yes it does what is written, NO it does not do what i want which is why im asking the question, i feel that is common problem for newcommers into programming. I thank you for an alternative way to my issue that is what i was looking for.

Comment: I suspect the only thing you're missing is understanding what a `break` statement does in a control loop. You have none, and it may come in *very* handy for this problem. I suggest that once you learn how one works, if this is really *your* code you will be able to solve this. Assuming this is all yours, you already know how an `if` construct works. You already know how to compare `std::string` against a literal. Now all you need to is do those in the right place, and *break* from your loop upon a true condition. Honestly, it's that simple. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the things have been already said in the comments:

Your problem is, that you expect the loop to check its condition continuously, which it does not.

```
while(name != "//") // here the condition is evaluated
{
    name = "//";    // here it is not 
     // the following code is executed, independent of the current name value
} // here the program jumps back to the loop condition, which is now false and it will not enter another time.
```

Like mentioned in the comments, a working alternative could be:

```
while(true)
{
    std::cin >> name;
    if(name == "//")
        break;
    else
        evaluateScore();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string name, grade;
    int score;
    int count1 = 0;
    int acount = 0;
    int bcount = 0;
    int ccount = 0;
    int dcount = 0;
    int fcount = 0;
    while (true) {  // keep running the loop
        cout << "Enter Student Name \n";
        cin >> name;
        if(name == "//")  // if "//" found, break the loop
            break;
        cout << "Enter Student Score \n";
        cin >> score;
        count1 += 1;
        if (score >= 90) {
            grade = "A";
            acount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
        else if (score >= 80) {
            grade = "B";
            bcount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
        else if (score >= 70) {
            grade = "C";
            ccount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
        else if (score >= 60) {
            grade = "D";
            dcount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
        else if (score <= 59) {
            grade = "F";
            fcount += 1;
            cout << name << " " << score << " " << grade << endl;
        }
    };
    cout << "Summary Report \n" << "Total Students Count: " << count1 << endl;
    cout << "A student count: " << acount << endl;
    cout << "B student count: " << bcount << endl;
    cout << "C student count: " << ccount << endl;
    cout << "D student count: " << dcount << endl;
    cout << "F student count: " << fcount << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Harsh: that should be `==` in the if check, probably just a copy/paste matter from the previous while loop condition?

Comment: @PaulT.: Ahhh!! my bad.. yes, it was a copy-paste. updated code. Thanks.